# Pass indexPath of selected row using Protocol

Tags: swift, uitableview, protocols

I am new to  MVC and protocols, but I am trying to adapt to MVC using protocols to pass data. I have a button on my tableview cell and I am trying to get the indexPath of the selected row to perform some action when that button is tapped. I created the protocol and set the delegate to the right VC. my issue is, how to get the selected indexPath through the delegate. Pardon my ignorance

**tableview Cell**

```
class PlaylistCell: UITableViewCell {

 var playButtonTappedDelegate: PlaylistCelldelegate!

@IBAction func PlayButton(_ sender: Any) {
    // Dont know how to get this Int, when cell is tapped
    playButtonTappedDelegate.handlePlayButton(for: self, for: <#Int#>)
}
```

}

**Protocol**

```
protocol PlaylistCelldelegate {
func handlePlayButton( for cell: PlaylistCell, for row: Int)
```

}

**I conformed to the delegate on this VC**

```
  class PlaylistVC: UIViewController, PlaylistCelldelegate {

    func handlePlayButton(for cell: PlaylistCell, for row: Int) {
        print("row\(row)")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlaylistCell", for: indexPath) as! PlaylistCell
        cell.playButtonTappedDelegate = self

        return cell
    }    
}
```

Comment: What does the button need to perform its action? If all it needs is a simple value, like the integer value of a row, then I would just inject each cell with that value and call it a day. You can pass the cell itself through the button's action and let the table get the path for you. This is an engineering problem and it's up to you to pick the one that is consistent with your coding, makes the most sense to you, consumes the least amount of resources, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `for row` parameter on your delegate method. Just send the cell.

Then you can find the cell's `indexPath` from the table view in your `handlePlayButton` implementation.

```
func handlePlayButton(for cell: PlaylistCell) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
}
```

Comment: If the rows are subject to change, this is the best solution. If the rows never change, just inject the cell with the row value and avoid this heavy lifting (asking the table to go through all of its reusable cells to find a row property).

Comment: @bsod A cell should never know or be told its row. It's fragile. Even if the rows are static now it could change in the future. Easier to write the code correctly the first time. And the table only needs to go through less than a dozen (typically) reusable cells. No heavy lifting.

Comment: @bsod, I don't understand what you mean by injecting the cell with the row value. Can you show an example, how I can achieve this?

Comment: Whether a cell should "never know" its row is debatable but your points are well taken. If the rows did change for some unexpected reason (hand of God, fragility, whatever), asking the table for the row would break the relationship with its data because they'd no longer match. What I mean by injecting the cell with its place in the array is simply giving the cell an integer property (that the data source gives a value to) that simply tells the button that its action is tied to this index in the underlying array.

Comment: @IamWayne really what I'm getting at is what does the button need to perform its action? Does it push to another view controller and all it needs is some string value like a UUID? Then just give the cell that value and let the button do its thing. But if its more complex and the rows are subject to change, the accepted answer is the way to go.

Comment: I got a playlist of audio songs, the button will present the audio player view controller and play the selected indexpath.